# How to avoid null key errors in dictionary?

Tags: c#, static-methods

How to avoid error if key is null?

```
//Getter/setter
public static Dictionary<string, string> Dictionary
{
    get { return Global.dictionary; }
    set { Global.dictionary = value; }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
Dictionary.Add("Key1", "Text1");
Dictionary["Key2"] <-error! so what can I write in the GET to avoid error?
```

Thanks.

regards

Comment: The code does not fit the question... Where is your key?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `TryGetValue`:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = ...;
string value;

if (dict.TryGetValue(key, out value))
{
    // value found
    return value;
}
else
{
    // value not found, return what you want
}
```

Comment: +1Use the try method, Don't use the contains method if you want to retrieve the value, it'll be inefficient as you'll effectively do the lookup twice

Comment: This answer is incorrect: `TryGetValue` throws an exception if the key is null.

Comment: @JasonBaley not sure this has anything to do with the answer, `Dictionary` doesn't support null keys. Additional discussion can be found in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632945/dictionary-with-null-key

Comment: @Grozz The question was how to avoid getting an error when a null key is provided for lookup in a dictionary.  Passing a null key to `TryGetValue` will still throw an error, so it doesn't answer the question.  In your answer, if `key` is null, an exception is thrown, so how does this address the original question?  He's trying to avoid the exception.

Comment: @JasonBaley please re-read the whole question carefully, not just the caption

Answer (score 13):

You can use the [`Dictionary.ContainsKey`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kw5aaea4.aspx) method.

So you'd write:

```
if (myDictionary.ContainsKey("Key2"))
{
    // Do something.
}
```

The other alternatives are to either wrap the access in a `try...catch` block or use [`TryGetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb347013.aspx) (see the examples on the MSDN page linked to).

```
string result = null;
if (dict.TryGetValue("Key2", out result))
{
    // Do something with result
}
```

The `TryGetMethod` is more efficient if you want do something with the result as you don't need a second call to get the value (as you would with the `ContainsKey` method).

(Of course, in both methods you'd replace "Key2" with a variable.)

Comment: I don't mean in a method but in the declaration!

Comment: @eman - I don't understand your question then. Can you update the code to show exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

An extension method:

```
public static TValue GetValue<TKey, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dic, TKey key)
{
    TValue result;
    return dic.TryGetValue(key, out result) ?
        result :
        default(TValue);
}
```

Usage:

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
   { "key", "value" }
};

string r1 = dic.GetValue("key"); // "value"
string r2 = dic.GetValue("false"); // null
```

Answer (score 0):

A key can never be null in a dictionary. A dictionary is a hashtable where by definition you need a non-empty key or the hash function cannot map to the corresponding element.

Comment: how to check if it's null and return an empty string?

Comment: I think that was his question, how to avoid that a `null` gets set as key...though, his code does not quiet fit that assumption.

Comment: In your code you never access the dictionary by key. You simply return a static dictionary. I don't understand what do you mean.

Comment: @Bobby, this can never happen. If you try to use null as a key in a dictionary you will get ArgumentNullException so you can never have a dictionary with null key.

Comment: Yes, I think that was his question, how to avoid that Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the wrong thing.  Don't return the dictionary, pass in a key and return the value.

```
public static string GetValue(string key)
{
    if(Global.dictionary.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        return Global.dictionary[key];
    }

    return ""; // or some other value
}
```