# Check if two list have the same items

Tags: c#, linq, list

I have two lists of integers, list1 and list2. The elements in the lists are the same, but the order is not important. How can I determine whether these lists are equal, ignoring the order of the elements? Is there a built-in method in C# that can do this, or do I need to write my own method?

```
var list1 = new List<int> {1,2,3};
var list2 = new List<int> {2,1,3};
```

Comment: I don't think there's anything built in... good candidate for an extension method

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Quickest way to compare two generic lists for differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795882/quickest-way-to-compare-two-generic-lists-for-differences)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That's what sets (e.g., [`HashSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) are for. Sets have no defined order, and [`SetEquals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346516%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) verifies whether the set and another collection contain the same elements.

```
var set = new HashSet<int>(list1);
var equals = set.SetEquals(list2);
```

Comment: Would this work if I have a list of objects instead of integers?

Comment: @Vahid Yeah it would.

Comment: @Vahid: it depends on if the object overrides `Equals` (+ `GetHashCode`). You can also pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the constructor of `HashSet` Read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952003/how-does-hashset-compare-elements-for-equality

Comment: Be aware that this algorithm declares sequence  {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1} equal to {1}. Is this what you want?

Comment: There is a MAJOR difference between a set and a list. A set does have only unique elements. This is a wrong answer to the question.

Comment: It's old, but if you implement a count camparer by the logic i assume you should actually get the correct answer despite reocurring elements, therefore extension like below should work:

`public static bool CompareList (this List<int> _initialList, List<int> _secondaryList)
{
 var set = new HashSet<int>(_initialList);
 var equals = set.SetEquals(_secondaryList);
 
 return equals ? _initialList.Count() == _secondaryList.Count() : false;
}`

Answer (score 20):

You can use `!Except` + `Any`:

```
bool list1InList2 = !list1.Except(list2).Any();
```

This checks not if both have the same items but if list1 is contained in list2(ignoring duplicates).

If you want to know  if `list2` is contained in `list1`, use:

```
bool list2InList1 = !list2.Except(list1).Any();
```

So you had to make both checks if you wanted to ensure that both lists contain the same items.

If you also want to take into account that both lists have the same size, precheck with `list1.Count==list2.Count`.
 But this check is not useful if you use a set method(see [Harald's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2281790/harald-coppoolse)), it doesn't make much sense to compare the counts if you ignore duplicates afterwards.

In general `HashSet<T>` has some nice and efficient methods to check if two sequences have the same items(ignoring duplicates), [dcastro already showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24361077/284240) one.

---

If you want an efficient solution to determine if two lists contain the same items, **same count** and **not ignoring duplicates** but **ignoring the order**(otherwise use `SequenceEquals`):

```
public static bool SequenceEqualsIgnoreOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    if(list1 is ICollection<T> ilist1 && list2 is ICollection<T> ilist2 && ilist1.Count != ilist2.Count)
        return false;

    if (comparer == null)
        comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;

    var itemCounts = new Dictionary<T, int>(comparer);
    foreach (T s in list1)
    {
        if (itemCounts.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            itemCounts[s]++;
        }
        else
        {
            itemCounts.Add(s, 1);
        }
    }
    foreach (T s in list2)
    {
        if (itemCounts.ContainsKey(s))
        {
            itemCounts[s]--;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return itemCounts.Values.All(c => c == 0);
}
```

Usage:

```
var list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 1 };
var list2 = new List<int> { 2, 1, 3, 2 };
bool sameItemsIgnoringOrder = list1.SequenceEqualsIgnoreOrder(list2); 
// false because same count and same items but 1 appaears twice in list1 but once in list2
```

---

If the order matters and duplicates count too, use:

```
bool sameItemsSameOrder = list1.SequenceEqual(list2);
```

Comment: @Rotem I wonder if this is faster than the method suggested by `dcastro`?

Comment: Thanks Tim, you mean `dcastro`'s method will ignore duplicates?

Comment: Thank you both for the clarification. I think I need to adapt this to my situation first to decide which one I need.

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse: you are right, so i have edited my answer

Comment: @HaraldCoppoolse: true, but as you have said, the `Count` check might be efficient but either the count doesnt matter(because duplicates are ignored anyway) or a non-set approach is needed anyway. I have removed my comments

Comment: @dcastro: maybe you want to delete your comments regarding `Count` because i have edited my answer. I dont think the `Count` check is useful in this case

Comment: @harald: added another extension method which you can use to check if two lists contain the same items but ignoring the order.

Comment: **NOTE** this approach does NOT support `null` items since `Dictionary` doesn't. `itemCounts.Add(s,1)` throws `ArgumentNullException` when `s` is `null`.

Comment: @N.Kudryavtsev: Good point. Maybe you could use this class as key: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22261282/284240

Answer (score 2):

It's old but i would modify answer by dcastro, and build in [extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods):

```
public static bool CompareList(this List<string> _initialList, List<string> _secondaryList) 
{ 
    var set = new HashSet<string>(_initialList); 
    var equals = set.SetEquals(_secondaryList); 
    return equals ? _initialList.Count() == _secondaryList.Count() : false; 
}
```

This way You would check both elements within the list with sets, but also count of elements helps you to check against excample given in coments like ***{0, 1, 1} vs {0 ,1}***

Additionaly by extension you can call it multiple times within the code.
You could modify it to compare against potential `null`.

```
public static bool CompareList(this List<string> _initialList, List<string>? _secondaryList) 
{
    //test if _secondaryList is null while initial is not
    if (_secondaryList == null) return false;

    var set = new HashSet<string>(_initialList); 
    var equals = set.SetEquals(_secondaryList); 
    return equals ? _initialList.Count() == _secondaryList.Count() : false; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without using linq.

```
 private static bool AreListsEqual(List<int> list1, List<int> list2)
 {
        var areListsEqual = true;

        if (list1.Count != list2.Count)
            return false;

        for (var i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
        {
            if (list2[i] != list1[i])
            {
                areListsEqual = false;
            }
        }

        return areListsEqual;
 }
```

Comment: There order is not important but your solution returns false when the numbers are not in the same order.

Comment: If you need to use a version as the above code, then you can actually use the core implemented `SequenceEquals` method.

Answer (score 1):

Use SequenceEqual against the ordered lists - e.g.

```
bool equal = list1.OrderBy(x => x).ToList().SequenceEqual(list2.OrderBy(x => x).ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Except](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

```
var result = list1.Except(list2).ToList();
```

`Except` returns those elements in first that do not appear in second

Comment: Why `string`? Also, where is the check for equality?

Comment: If `list1` is empty  this returns an empty list which does not mean that both are equal. It also fails if list1 is a subset of list2. Apart from that it is not necessary to create another collection just to check if both lists are equal.