# Cannot convert expanded class to IList

Tags: c#, list

Given the following classes:

```
public class MyList<T> : IList<T>, ICloneable
{ ... }

public class PinList : MyList<SomeClass>, ICloneable, IEquatable<PinList>
{ ... }
```

Why wont this work?

```
public void Main()
{
    PinList pins = new PinList();
    Method2(pins); // Does not work

    List<string> strings = new List<string>();
    Method2(strings); // WORKS
}

public void Method2(object obj)
{
    // returns TRUE
    obj.GetType().GetInterfaces().Any(t => t.IsGenericType && t.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IList<>)); 

    var things = ((IList)obj).Cast<object>().ToList();
    // Unable to cast object of type 'PinList' to type 'System.Collections.IList'.
}
```

I've tried hard casting the obj to obj.GetType(), and I've looked on google to no avail.

Comment: Note that you could cast to `IEnumerable` if you're just trying to call `Cast` on `obj`, but I don't see the purpose in what you're doing.

Comment: Please check my answer, maybe you're wasting your time using custom lists while you might be able to stay with out-of-the-box collections.

Comment: `IList<T>` is different from `IList`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't work, because your class does not implement `IList`.

- It directly implements `IList<SomeClass>`, `ICloneable` and `IEquatable<PinList>`.
- It indirectly ([via `IList<SomeClass>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx)) implements `ICollection<SomeClass>`, `IEnumerable<SomeClass>` and `IEnumerable`.

One might expect `IList<T>` to implement `IList`, but this is not the case. If you think about it, this makes sense: `IList` guarantees that arbitrary objects can be added to the list. An `IList<T>`, however, only allows objects of type `T` or a subtype thereof to be added. Thus, if `IList<T>` implemented `IList`, the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) would be violated.

You don't have this problem with `IEnumerable`, since there's no way to *add* items to an `IEnumerable`. Thus, `IEnumerable<T>` satisfies all contracts that `IEnumerable` satisfies, and, hence, `IEnumerable<T>` implements `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Must be why List<string> works and my class doesn't!  Ug, thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

The class implements `IList<T>`, not `IList`.  If you want it to implement `IList` you'll need to add it to the class's definition, and add appropriate methods for the various methods of that interface.

Answer (score 1):

Just a [hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

While [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public class List<T> : IList<T>, ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, 
    IEnumerable, IList, ICollection, IReadOnlyList<T>, IReadOnlyCollection<T>
```

I see `IList` implemented on `List<T>` but `IList<T>` doesn't also implement `IList`!

### ???

See your custom list derived class signature:

```
public class PinList : MyList<SomeClass>, ICloneable, IEquatable<PinList>
```

I got a surprise when I saw `IEquatable<PinList>`. Are you trying to implement a custom list just because you want to be able to detemine if two given lists of type `PinList` have the same items?

`HashSet<T>` to the rescue! See this other Q&A: [Check if two list have the same items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361054/check-if-two-list-have-the-same-items)

### And...

Perhaps you're also implementing a custom list just because you want to be able to make it *cloneable*, and I would say that it's a bad design decision.

- If you need to just clone the list and not its items, `list.ToList()` is enough.
- If you need to clone the list and its items should be also cloned: `list.Select(o => (SomeType)o.Clone()).ToList()`. Obviously stored objects should implement `ICloneable`. In the other hand, if you thought that you don't want to repeat yourself, you could use an extension method:

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
      public static IList<T> CloneList<T>(this IList<T> source)
           where T : ICloneable
           => source.Select(o => (T)o.Clone()).ToList(); 
}
```

...and call it wherever you want: `list.CloneList()`.

So... No need to implement `IList<T>` or derive `List<T>` anymore!

Comment: Wow thanks. I will have to look to see if this will affect a lot of code and worth the effort to change it. (Working from an inherited code base)

Comment: @Tizz Oops! So you inherited design smells :( :D

Comment: Yea well, nothing I can do right now. ... So how would I get that cast to work if I cant change from IList<>? Tried (cellVal as IList<obj.GetType()>).Cast<object>().ToList() ... it doesnt like that

Comment: @Tizz Do you mean how you cast an `IList<T>` to `IList`?

Comment: Yes, I got it: dynamic convertedIList = Convert.ChangeType(obj, obj.GetType()); Now I can iterate through each item and create a List<object> as I want!  Thank you for your help!!!!

Comment: @Tizz But if you use dynamic typing, you don't need to change the type anymore! :D

Answer (score 1):

You PinList implements IList<T>, but you are trying to cast obj to IList.

IList<T> and IList are 2 different interfaces.

Change your class to

```
public class MyList<T> : IList, ICloneable
{ ... }
```

you'll be able to get obj converted to IList.

When converting, you do not need this long statement

```
 var things = ((IList)obj).Cast<object>().ToList();
```

Just

```
IList things = (IList)obj;
```

or

```
IList things = obj as IList;
```

will do your job.  First one will throw exception if obj is not convertible to IList while the 2nd one just return null.