# How to compare all items in the lists are equal?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list,in which every item is a list of stings themselves.
How do I check whether all the individual items are same?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var myList = new List<List<string>>();
    var myItem1 = new List<string> { "str1", "str2" };
    var myItem2 = new List<string> { "str1", "str2" };

    myList.Add(myItem1);
    myList.Add(myItem2);

    var total = ??  // <- I'm stuck here

    Console.WriteLine(total);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Now I want to  check if every item inside myList are equal.
I did try this one:[Check if two list have the same items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24361054/check-if-two-list-have-the-same-items), but could not resolve.

Comment: Does order of the items or duplicates matter?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [simple google search would bring the answer to it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__). Tip: if this method returns no items - its equal

Comment: When you say "could not resolve" when attempting your linked answer - what result did you get and what have you tried?

Comment: @AlexandruPuiu, no does not matter.

Comment: @T.S., doing in simple foreach loop way is not what I was after.I was trying for an elegant LINQ solution. May be I should have added that.Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the update. It was not listed in the question

Comment: So in your example, do you expect the result to be `false`, since `myList` contains both `"str1"` and `"str2"` (which are not equal)?

Comment: @RufusL, No I want it to be true since both the items in myList(myitem1 and myItem2) are containing same items.Basically I want to compare between myItem1 and myItem2 and if they contain same items,regardless of the order,it should return true.Also, please please note myList can contain  many items-muItem1,2,3.. so on, wanna compare between them all.

Comment: Ok, I think that wasn't quite clear based on the answers you're getting. Next question is if `myItem1` had a duplicate entry, like `{ "str1", "str2", "str2" }`, should the equality comparison *still* return `true` or would it now be `false` since the count is different than `myItem2`?

Comment: that will not arise in my case as it will be sent as Disntict.

Comment: try var status = myItem1.SequenceEqual(myItem2);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check if all the lists contain the exact same elements, we can use the `SequenceEqual` method, which compares both the elements themselves and their order. Since you said that order doesn't matter, however, then we must order the lists first when we do the comparison.

The following line of code returns `true` if `All` the lists (except the first one), when reduced to `Distinct` items and then sorted (`OrderBy`), are equal to the `First` list (when reduced to `Distinct` items and sorted):

```
bool allAreEqual = myList
    .Skip(1)
    .All(subList => subList
        .Distinct()
        .OrderBy(item => item)
        .SequenceEqual(myList.First().Distinct().OrderBy(item => item)));
```

---

Instead of doing it all in one line, it would be easier to read (in my opinion) and better performing to first get the distinct, ordered lists, and then do the comparison (otherwise we're ordering the first item for each of the other items):

```
var sortedLists = myList.Select(list => list.Distinct().OrderBy(item => item));
var allAreEqual = sortedLists.Skip(1).All(list => list.SequenceEqual(sortedLists.First()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307172/check-if-all-items-are-the-same-in-a-list) which should output true if the list's elements are all the same.

For your code:

```
if (myList.Any(item => !Enumerable.SequenceEqual(item, myList[0])))
```