# Multi-Key Dictionary where either key can be null

Tags: c#, class, dictionary

I am trying to create a multi-key dictionary where the values are enumerable. The goal is to be able to perform a lookup using the first key, and if there are no matches, to perform anther lookup using the second key.

Here is my solution so far:

```
public class MultipleKeyDictionary<TEmployeeIDKey, TBadgeNumberKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<TValue>
{
    private object m_data_lock = new object();
    private Dictionary<TBadgeNumberKey, TEmployeeIDKey> badgeNumberDictionary = new Dictionary<TBadgeNumberKey, TEmployeeIDKey>();
    private Dictionary<TEmployeeIDKey, TValue> empIDDictionary = new Dictionary<TEmployeeIDKey, TValue>();


    public void AddValue(TEmployeeIDKey empIDKey, TBadgeNumberKey badgeKey, TValue value)
    {
        lock (m_data_lock)
        {
            badgeNumberDictionary[badgeKey] = empIDKey;
            empIDDictionary[empIDKey] = value;
        }
    }

    public TValue getByBadgeNumber(TBadgeNumberKey badgeKey)
    {
        lock (m_data_lock)
            return empIDDictionary[badgeNumberDictionary[badgeKey]];
    }

    public TValue getByEmployeeID(TEmployeeIDKey empIDKey)
    {
        lock (m_data_lock)
            return empIDDictionary[empIDKey];
    }


    public bool TryGetValueByEmployeeID(TEmployeeIDKey empIDKey, out TValue value)
    {

        return empIDDictionary.TryGetValue(empIDKey, out value);

    }

    public bool TryGetValueByBadgeKey(TBadgeNumberKey badgeNumberKey, out TValue value)
    {
        value = default(TValue);

        if (badgeNumberDictionary.TryGetValue(badgeNumberKey, out TEmployeeIDKey empIDKey))
        {
            return empIDDictionary.TryGetValue(empIDKey, out value);
        }

        return false;
    }


    public IEnumerator<TValue> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return empIDDictionary.Values.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
  }
```

The problem is that both EmployeeID and BadgeNumber, or either of them could be null.
How can I modify this so that I can perform my desired lookup if either key can be null?

**EDIT:** **This is the code I am using to perform the Lookup where gateLogGroups is a group of Gate Logs grouped by BadgeNumber and EmployeeID and invoiceRecords is of class MultipleKeyDictionary**

```
        foreach (var cardNumberGroup in gateLogGroups)
        {
            invoiceRecords.TryGetValueByEmployeeID(cardNumberGroup.Key.EmpIDNum, out InvoiceRecord invoiceRecord);

            if (invoiceRecord == null)
            {
                invoiceRecords.TryGetValueByBadgeKey(cardNumberGroup.Key.CardNumber, out invoiceRecord);

                if (invoiceRecord == null)
                {
                    exceptions.Add(new GateLogWithNoMatchingInvoiceException(cardNumberGroup.GateLogs.ElementAt(0), invoiceRecords.ElementAt(0).InvoiceHeaderId));
                    continue;
                }
            }
```

Comment: The only way I know of is to wrap your value eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632945/dictionary-with-null-key (second answer)

Comment: You just have to decide what the semantics are for `null` keys. Nothing prevents your type from allowing them.

Comment: @AluanHaddad the way I have it currently makes it to where if I search by badgeNumber, but employeeID is null then the key that the badgeNumber dictionary returns is null. Meaning I am not able to use it in my lookup using my employeeID dictionary. That is the main issue I am having.

Comment: If that result means there is no employee, you can check for it like `if (badgeNumberDictionary[badgeKey] == null) throw new KeyNotFoundException();`

Comment: I feel like the phrase *"multiple key dictionary"* is completely inaccurate, as the class does not implement a dictionary interface. You have two dictionaries, with different key and value types, and a class that provides methods to get a value using one of the two different types.

Comment: Can you please share sample code of what you mean? In otherwords, what code would you like the user to be able to write in order to retrieve a value, where either badge or employee id could be null?

Comment: When you're adding values, if badge number and/or employee id are `null`, then the associated value will overwrite any previous `null` key that was added to the associated dictionary. So it doesn't seem feasible that you could accept `null` in a lookup method for either of those "keys" and still return an accurate value.

Comment: A null EmployeeID doesn't mean that the Employee doesn't exist. The employee data is "bad" and there are two possible identifiers: BadgeNumber and EmployeeID. For each record, both fields could be populated, neither fields could be populated, or either could be populated. If even one of those fields are populated, I want to be able to try and find the employee based on that field.

I.E. Search by EmployeeID - EmployeeID is null so no match.
Search by BadgeNumber - Match found but returns EmployeeID which is null so I am unable to use it to get the Value from the BadgeNumber Dictionary.

Comment: @RufusL Added example code for calling the TryGetValueFunctions. I agree with your comment. What other solution could I use to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: The code you posted does not make much sense to me. It seems that you only use `TBadgeNumberKey` to look up the `TEmployeeIDKey` value. Any code that already has `TEmployeeIDKey` could get the employee record with a _single_ key, and there is a 1-to-1 relationship between `TEmployeeIDKey` and `TBadgeNumberKey`. In other words, this isn't a multi-key dictionary, but rather just a single dictionary that optionally supports a kind of aliasing between keys. In any case, the `null` issue is well-documented, and work-arounds are similarly well-documented. See duplicates.

Comment: From the code you've shown, BadgeNumber is just a way to lookup an EmployeeId. But the value associated with EmployeeId is the data we care about. When adding records, if EmployeeId is `null`, then `empIDDictionary[empIDKey] = value;` will work fine for the first record with a null EmployeeId, but if another one comes along, that line of code will overwrite the previous data. So I guess my question is, how can you ever find the data associated with a null EmployeeId in this scenario?

Comment: @RufusL This is my issue that I am having. I understand that the way I went about trying to acheive my goal is incorrect, but I am not sure how to correct it. Essentially what I am after is some sort of Dictionary lookup where I can use either key to find a match even if one of the keys is 'null'

Comment: You can do it if one key is null, but not both, by using a Tuple that contains both as a key.

Comment: @RufusL Wouldn't using a Tuple make it where both keys have to match? There is the possibility that the EmployeeID will match, but the BadgeNumber doesn't and vice versa. This is okay and expected.

Comment: Technically a custom class that overrides the `Equals` method would be better (so it handle null values and avoid querying the dictionary keys), but with tuples you could do: `public TValue getByEmployeeID(TEmployeeIDKey empIDKey) { lock (_mDataLock) return _empIdDictionary.First(i => i.Key.Item1.Equals(empIDKey)).Value; }`

Comment: @RufusL that makes sense. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Here's an untested version that might do the trick: https://dotnetfiddle.net/eTcKxt