# is it .net bug ? should i report this? convert T to int or int?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

i have component WHERE T can be `int or int?` with params like

```
@typeparam T
@inject DictService _dhttp;


<MudAutocomplete T="string" @bind-Value="ValueString" Label="@Label" For="()=>ValueString" SearchFunc="@SearchFunc" 
             ResetValueOnEmptyText="true" CoerceValue="true" 
             OpenIcon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Search" AdornmentColor="Color.Primary"
             @attributes=AllOtherAttributes />




[Parameter]
public Expression<Func<T>>? For { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public string? Label { get; set; }


private T _value = default!;

[Parameter]
public T Value
{
    get => _value;
    set
    {
        if (!Equals(value, _value))
        {
            _value = value;
            if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate) ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_value);
        }
    }
}

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<T?> ValueChanged { get; set; } 

private string? _valueString ;
public string? ValueString 
{
    get{
        return _valueString!;
    }
    set
    {
        if(!Equals(value, _valueString))
        {
            _valueString = value;
            int? valueInt = _dict!.Values.Where(... some logic to get in val or not)

            if (valueInt is null)
            {
                ValueString = null;
```

and now this should work for both cases?!? set 0 if `int` and null if `int?` ??

**this.Value = (T)(object)default!;**

but instead of i have to do

```
              if (typeof(T) == typeof(int))
                   this.Value = (T)(object)0; 
               else
                    this.Value = (T)(object)default!;

            }
            else this.Value = (T)(object)valueInt;           

            if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)  ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_value);
        }
    }
}
```

if i do not do this way then in debug i see that if `T is int` then `(T)(object)default!` like crashes? it should set it to 0 !?
it throws no error. **it not go to next line** , it just returns to app without changing value of `this.Value` witch is int in this case. value stays as it was from previous run

is it a .net blazor bug? or am missing something here ?

Here is some githup repo that shows this issue

https://github.com/d00lar/TconverterFails

in this line

```
 <MudSelectItem  Value="TConverter.ChangeType<T>(item.Key)">@item.Value</MudSelectItem>
```

if i do casting based on this int/int? switch then it will wotk fine otherwise throw as in topic

Comment: It is not really clear what the actual question is. I would suggest a *minimal reproducible example*. Also, you might want to explain your actual goal. Generics typically do not work well with nullables, and if you need to check the type of your generic, it seem likely that generics is the wrong solution for your problem.

Comment: ok i edited and pushed code example witch fails if i do not cast it this way based on int/int Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overcomplicating your cast.

Just use `default` which will set type `int` to `0`, and type `int?` to `null`.

Index.razor:

```
@page "/"


<MyComponent T="int" />
<MyComponent T="int?" />
```

Component:

```
@using System.ComponentModel
@typeparam T

<div>
    <input type="text" @bind-value="@ValueString" />

    <span>@(Value == null ? "null" : Value)</span>
</div>

@code {
    T Value { get; set; }

    string _valueString = "";

    string? ValueString
    {
        get
        {
            return _valueString!;
        }
        set
        {
            _valueString = value;

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                this.Value = default;
            }
            else this.Value = TConverter.ChangeType<T>(value); ;

            Console.WriteLine(_valueString);
        }
    }

    public static class TConverter
    {
        public static T ChangeType<T>(object value)
        {
            return (T)ChangeType(typeof(T), value);
        }

        public static object ChangeType(Type t, object value)
        {
            TypeConverter tc = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(t);
            return tc.ConvertFrom(value);
        }

        public static void RegisterTypeConverter<T, TC>() where TC : TypeConverter
        {

            TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(T), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(TC)));
        }
    }
}
```

`TConverter` source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1833128/2286743

## Fix to provided [link](https://github.com/d00lar/TconverterFails):

I can see in your approach that your understanding of how to implement components needs to be expanded. I suggest you go through the documentation provided by Microsoft, and improve your understanding.

As a side note, using a dictionary is not the right way of doing it, since the `Key` in a Dictionary cannot be null. This can however be overcome as mentioned here: [Why doesn't Dictionary<TKey, TValue> support null key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632945/why-doesnt-dictionarytkey-tvalue-support-null-key)

#### index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using MyApplication.Shared

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<IntStrDictMudSelectComponent @bind-Value="@intvar" Data="@Data" For="@(()=>intvar)" />

@code {
    private int intvar = 1;

    Dictionary<int, string> Data = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
        { 1, "Value 1" },
        { 2, "Value 2" },
        { 3, "Value 3" },
        { 4, "Value 4" },
        { 5, "Value 5" },
        { 6, "Value 6" }
    };
}
```

#### IntStrDictMudSelectComponent.razor

```
@using System.Linq.Expressions
@typeparam T

<MudSelect T="T" @bind-Value="@Value" For="@For">
    @foreach (var item in Data)
    {
        <MudSelectItem Value="item.Key">@item.Value</MudSelectItem>
    }
</MudSelect>


@code {
    [EditorRequired]
    [Parameter]
    public Expression<Func<T>>? For { get; set; }

    T _value = default!;

    [EditorRequired]
    [Parameter]
    public T Value
    {
        get => _value;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(value, _value))
            {
                _value = value;
                if (ValueChanged.HasDelegate)
                    ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(_value);
            }
        }
    }
    
    [EditorRequired]
    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<T> ValueChanged { get; set; }

    [EditorRequired]
    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<T, string> Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks but if i do TConverter.ChangeType<T>(item.Key) and T is int and item.key is int
then i recive exception Int32Converter cannot convert from System.Int32

Comment: @d00lar, well obviously you did something wrong.

Debug and check what `item.Key` is.

Comment: ok for simple examples this work but for a bit more complex no 
Can You Please check this repo ? i uploaded it with this particular error
https://github.com/d00lar/TconverterFails

Comment: @d00lar, I don't see the repo you are referring to. 404 on your link, and your account only shows 2 repos.

Comment: ok now - sorry it was private by mistake

Comment: @d00lar, your testing approach is flawed. Your conversion is happening in the component, and shouldn't. You need to provide the component with `Dictionary<T, string>`, and not create the dictionary in the component. When testing, do correct testing by implementing the same as the use-case.

Comment: @d00lar, my answer was updated with a fix to your problem.

Comment: thanks. i known that i can fix this way. but this way i canot bind to `int?` property of model. wanted to handle both cases. and as it will be used in many places then i wanted simple component calls by just parsing enum as parameter to this IntStrDictMudSelectComponent. and based on this enum take this dictionary from service IN COMPONENT itself so i does need to call this service in 'parrent' component. and pass in list as You did - thats why i did it hardcoded in component itself in this github example. and conversion is in component because of this.

Comment: beside of 'design' issue still why this conversion fails and this tconverter fails ? it should not imho? is it .net bug ?. is what i sad realy terrible idea? to take this dict from service based on enum parameter in component itself? if i do test it right?  thanks and regards

Comment: If you are using an enum, take the enum and create a `List<SomeClass>` where the class has a `T Value` and `string Name` properties. It will work like the dictionary. Then you don't cast. You just use `T` (the enum). That's what I was trying to show you. Try and understand the solution and not criticize.

Comment: i not criticize in any place sorry if You thought so it was not my intention ;) thanks for all! I just wanted to show my point of view and why i chosed to do like this. Yes i known that it can be Tvalue in class but how to get from api list of Tvalue and string name?? api call have no concept of sending T so it known what to return?. list of keyvaluepair<int,string> is easy?? ps still why this conversion fails and this tconverter fails ? is it .net bug ?

Comment: @d00lar, I can guarantee you it's not a bug. An exception like this will only throw if it cannot be cast to the type you are targeting. From the API you will have a given type passed to your client, this type can be sent as the generic type in the component which will require no casting if you only use this type, and return that type in the `ValueChanged` parameter. As a rule of thumb, generics should be done without casting in most cases. The most common cast will be from `string` to `T` or vice-versa.